# How to access kotlin libray glm from java the right way?

Tags: java, kotlin, glm-math

Im trying to use the kotlin library [glm](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/glm) in my java project. I want to use the method `translate` from interface [matrix_transform](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/glm/blob/v1.0.1/src/main/kotlin/glm_/matrix_transform.kt).

Currently im trying to call this function with
`glm_.matrix_transform.DefaultImpls.translate()`. But i dont understand the first parameter. The paramter name is `$this`. What do i have to pass there? I tried to pass an instantiation of `glm_.matrix_transform.DefaultImpls` but it doesnt work. Where does the parameter `$this` come from anyway? If have a look at the interface there is no parameter `$this`. Am i using the kotlin library in the right way? The use of `glm_.matrix_transform.DefaultImpls` was just a wild guess from my side.

The [github readme page](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/glm) tells me to use it like this (in kotlin):

```
...
import glm_.glm

fun camera(translate: Float, rotate: Vec2): Mat4 {
  ...
  var view = glm.translate(Mat4(1.0f), Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -translate))
  ...
return ...
}
```

But if i do so i get the message:

> Non-static 'tanslate(...)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Im calling function `translate` inside an object.

this is my my maven pom file:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
  <id>jitpack.io</id>
  <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.kotlin-graphics</groupId>
  <artifactId>glm</artifactId>
  <version>v1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think you need to use the `glm_.Java.glm` to access the global functions.

Comment: you are right. This works. Thanks!